# «Проездить», «проехаться» - как образовать личные формы

Tags: глаголы, спряжение

Дан глагол **проедешься** - I спряжение, образован от глагола *проехаться*.

Дан глагол **проездишься** - II спряжение, образован от глагола *проездиться*.

Собственно, а как запомнить и понять, от какого инфинитива образуется личная форма глагола? ***Проехаться** - «х» заменяется на «д» и образуется форма «проедешься»* - так объяснять написание?

Comment: В МАС указано, что глагол "проездиться" устаревший, и только там рассматривается значение "проехаться".